# Diagonalizing Matrices

Tags: linear-algebra

Show that if $A$ and $B$ are two $n \times n$ matrices that both have the same
diagonalizing matrix $X$, then $AB = BA$

I have the following answer, I just don't understand it completely. Can someone help explain it to me?

$X^{−1}AX = D$

$X^{−1}BX = E$

$X^{−1}ABX = DE = ED = X^{−1}BAX$
Therefore:
$AB = BA$

The third step is where I get confused.

Comment: Here $X$ is a non-singular matrix, then you may multiply $X$ to the left side and multiply $X^{-1}$ to the right.

Comment: Checking your title for typos goes a loooooong way to asking a nice question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since $ED = DE$, you have $X(ED) X^{-1} = X(DE) X^{-1}$. Also, $I = X^{-1} X$, so we have \begin{eqnarray}
X(ED) X^{-1} &=&  XEID X^{-1} \\
&=& XEX^{-1} XD X^{-1} \\
&=&  BA \\
&=&  X(DE) X^{-1} \\
&=&  XDIE X^{-1} \\
&=&  XDX^{-1} XE X^{-1} \\
&=&  AB
\end{eqnarray}

($ED = DE$ because any two diagonal matrices commute.)

Comment: Your last $BA$ should be $AB$.

Comment: @julien: Thanks! Feel free to edit. My typing skills are pedestrian, so I cut and paste a lot...

Comment: You are very welcome!

Answer (score 1):

$$X^{−1}ABX = \underbrace{X^{−1}AX}_{D}\underbrace{X^{−1}BX}_{E}$$

and diagonal matrices commute, so $DE = ED$

Comment: @julien I am not sure what you are saying, I only use that $X$ is non-singular and that $E$ and $D$ are diagonal matrices.

Comment: What I am saying actually does not make any sense. My weak English is playing me some tricks tonight. Sorry.

Answer (score 1):

The third step is not right. May not always be true that $X^{-1}ABX={X^{-1}BAX}$.
If $AB\ne{BA}$, then for example if $AB = U$, $BA = V$ and $X^{-1}UX\ne{X^{-1}VX}$.
Also matrices $D$ and $E$ are not diagonal.